# Embedded Google Sheet in iFrame causes the parent to scroll to 0, 0 position after loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, iframe, google-docs

I am facing a strange issue when embedding a Google Sheet in an iframe. I have a long HTML page containing a list of divs along with an embedded iframe for a Google Sheet. When I scroll to the iframe while its content is still loading, the page scrolls automatically to the top (0,0 position).

I've created a sample on CodeSandbox to replicate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-microservice-vj6zy1?file=/index.html

I'm looking for a solution that will allow the page to maintain its scroll position while the Google Sheet iframe is loading.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?